# multiple ajax calls into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Possible Duplicate ([Call multiple ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051226/call-multiple-ajax-calls)).

I'm trying to use jQuery/AJAX to load to an array. This is my code that works perfectly for one AJAX call.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/ex",
        data: dataEx,
        success: function (result) {
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
                arr[i] = new arrayClass(result[i]);
            //arr is an array of arrClass objects
        },
        error: function (error) {
            $("#divError").html(error.responseText);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Now lets say I want to load in dataEx1, dataEx2, and dataEx3. I have tried multiple solutions, the following is one of many that did not work.

```
    var list = ["1", "2", "3"];
    var i = 0;
    var runNextAjax = function () {
        var data = "dataEx" + list.pop();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Ex",
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                for (i; i < (result.length + i); i++)
                    arr[i] = new arrayClass(result[i]);
                if (list.length > 0)
                    runNextAjax();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $("#divError").html(error.responseText);
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
    runNextAjax();
```

I understand it has to do with how AJAX doesn't execute sequentially. How do I fix this?

Comment: [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) is a great library for this :)

Comment: Does the data have to be loaded one after the other?  Or can you do it in parallel as long as the right data goes in the right place?  Hint: loading in parallel can be a lot faster and a bit simpler to implement.

Comment: jfriend00, the data does not need to be loaded one after another. Teach me how to do this magic you speak of.